# adding stl libraries and include files to a visual studio project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

I am new in VSc++ and hence some simple questions :)

I created a c++ project in VS 2012 and now I want to add stl to it, How can I do this?

For example when I am adding this include to a source code, I am getting error that the header file is not recognized.

```
#include <fstream.h>
```

How can I setup a VS c++ project t use STL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard C++ library haven't had headers ending with `.h` in many years. What you want is `<fstream>`.

I recommend a good reference like [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).

Comment: thanks. I made the changes and now I am getting error on this line:  ofstream myFile; that ofstream is not known. What is the problem>

Comment: @mans All standard library classes is in a [namespace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) called `std`. You have to use e.g. `std::ofstream` instead. Besides the reference I think you need to get new books or tutorials, ones made the last ten years or so.